# Is it possible to find age and gender of a specific user using Firebase Analytics in mobile app?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have Firebase Analytics integrated into my mobile apps (Android and iOS). Every mobile user has a unique ID that is used to set up the Firebase SDK with. 
Is it possible to find out age bucket and a gender of a specific user? I've been looking at User explorer on Google Analytics console but could not find a way to connect user ID and age/gender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Is it possible to find out age bucket and gender for a specific user?*

**No**. As per https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en#thresholds

> Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from
> inferring the demographics or interests of individual users. When a
> report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or
> secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold
> may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report

So **when you try to combine the User ID with demographics data, each row in your report contains info about only 1 user, which is below threshold, thus demographics data gets hidden**.

If you need user-level precision for gender/age etc... with Firebase/GA, the 2 ways I see are:

- **ask users** (eg date of birth field in their profile settings)
- use an **external data enrichment tool**

You **save that data** against each **User ID** in **user properties / custom dimensions** so you can retrieve it at will.